# Why "sich sich"?

Tags: pronoun, reflexive

From Grammatik Aktiv B1+ published by Cornelesen, chapter 1 exercise 3:

> Sie schreibt, dass sie **sich sich** in einer schwierigen Situation befindet, und bittet mich um Hilfe.

As I understand "she writes that she finds herself in a difficult situations, and asks me for help".

I don't understand why "sich sich". Is this a typo?

The first book in the series was great, but so far this second book seems inferior.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a typo. The second "sich" has no place there and is wrong.

Another possibility is, that the second "sich" should be a "sicher":

Sie schreibt, dass sie sich sich**er** in einer schwierigen Situation befindet, und bittet mich um Hilfe.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a typo. The second 'sich' is superfluous.